# WebApi 2 with JS as FrontEnd, How to secure pages for not authorized users?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a `WebApi 2` project where i have a `Cookie Authentication API`, once the user has been `Authenticated` he can use all other `APIs`, my front-end is based on `jquery` and `js`. Now **i would merge the front-end project to the back-end**, so i've added my `JS` project as static files to my `WebApi 2` project.

But now i would secure some of pages which users should reach **only if the user is** `Authenticated`.
Here is my project structure:

[Project structure screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVCjJ.png)

By default the user is redirected to `index.html` and then he can access the `menu.html` but `menu.html` must be served to the user only if he is `Authenticated`, i've read in other similar questions that i should use something like a middleware, but i would know if it's the right approach to serve the front end as static files and if it's the wrong one, what sould i do in my case?

Comment: There is some info here on authenticating routes,. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/authorization-using-web-api/#:~:text=Web%20API%20provides%20a%20built,)%2C%20without%20invoking%20the%20action.&text=Create%20a%20new%20Project.

Comment: @Keith it's an MVC based with Razor pages example... i have just "static pages" in html..